# Sincronizar vista de dos capas (div) con el Scroll Horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

En mi pagina tengo dos capas (div) con scroll horizontal cada una... como puedo hacer para al mover un scroll el otro tambien se mueva para sincronizar la vista de ambas capas ??
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <div id="divGrid" align="center" style=" overflow-x:auto;" > 
 <div id="cc" align="center" style="position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 0px; right:0px; opacity: 0.8; display:none;  overflow-x:auto;"> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Sería más fácil de entender si compartieras algo de código.

Comment: Shaz no hace falta...fijate si la pagina tiene dos capas (div) y cada capa tiene un scroll horizontal al mover un scroll el otro scroll tambien debe moverse ...de esa forma se sincronizan las vistas de las capas....

Answer (score 1):

Como no pones código en la pregunta, voy a poner un ejemplo de cómo quedaría sincronizar dos `div` del mismo tamaño (aunque el código es escalable a cualquier número de `div`s):

La idea es poner un controlador del evento `scroll` en los `div` y cuando se lance, actualizar el resto de `div`s con la misma cantidad de scroll. Esto se puede hacer con [`scrollLeft()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/) (sin parámetros para leer el valor del `div` en el que se ha hecho scroll, y con un valor para ajustar el scroll de los otros `div`s):

```js
$(".contenedor").on("scroll", function() {
  $(".contenedor").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

```css
.contenedor {
  height:50px;
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  overflow:scroll;
}

.scroll {
  width:1000px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="scroll"></div>
</div>

<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="scroll"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hola y gracias Alvaro Montoro... fijate en esto veo que las div tienen la misma class esto no se puede hacer en mi ejemplo por q son diferentes .....no c puede hacer por el  id de la div???

Comment: voy a editar mi pregunta ..voy a agregar el codigo

Comment: aunque es exactmente la idea...

Comment: Cambia las clases en Los selectores y debería funcionar igual

Comment: si pudieras ser un poquito mas grafico soy nuevo en esto,....

Comment: Gracias ..Alvaro Montoro ...pude resolver desde tu ejemplo ..claro mi codigo c puede optimizar pero soy novato en esto....Mira mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

No se exactamente cuál es tu propósito y si he entendido bien tu pregunta, pero se me ocurre que metas los dos divs dentro de otro div y que sea éste último el que muevas, así se moverían los dos a la vez.

Comment: la idea  es hacerlo con javascript o jquery ...

Answer (score 0):

a cada div agregue el evento OnScroll que llama a una funcion JavaScript cuando existe dezplazamiento

esta son las funciones JavaScript

```
function ScrollCC() {
             var cc = document.getElementById('cc');
             var dg = document.getElementById('divGrid');
             dg.scrollLeft = cc.scrollLeft;
         }
```

y esta otra

```
function ScrollDG() {
             var cc = document.getElementById('cc');
             var dg = document.getElementById('divGrid');
             cc.scrollLeft = dg.scrollLeft;
         }
```